# Copy questions from Super User?

Tags: support, questions, migration, private-beta

Can we copy closed questions from Super User, or do you just want non-duplicative stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Ivo - just copy and paste.

Don't forget we're copying questions that are **already closed** so there's nothing else that can be done with them *at the moment*.

If the site takes off and a migration path opens up then we should go through the closed questions reopening them and then reclose by voting to migrate - but only if they haven't already been copied.

This might need a reset of the vote counts though as you can only vote to close/re-open a question once each way. Unless Super User moderators aren't affected by this.

**UPDATE**

Now that a migration path from Super User is open, voting to close is on the cards - but be sensible. If you know that the question already exists here, just vote to close as off topic. Or flag for moderator attention if you don't have enough rep on SU.

Comment: Moderators can always simply reopen then migrate

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be good to have proper question migration from SU to be implemented at some point. Just copying questions over manually strikes me as highly inelegant. However this probably needs to wait until the beta period ends.

Answer (score 1):

I already copied some questions from all over the Trilogy during the proposal phase.

Unless we get a proper migration I would simply copy/paste, but be sure to do some cherry picking as not every question is worth being brought over